# RoadMap Matching from Images

Tags: computer-vision

So, basically I have two roadmap binary images. The first one let's say is the roadmap of a whole city and the second one is a subnet (that may also be rotated). I am looking for an algorithm-method which will find the subnet inside the 1st roadmap. I thought it would be an easy task, however, I am struggling to find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us what you have, what you tried, samples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYTaS.png) For example that's the roadmap of an area that I have. You can choose any part of this image to use as the subnet (stack doesn't let me upload another image). This subnet can also be rotated. I was thinking of some graph matching method or RANSAC but I couldn't find anything useful.